# single word for a challenging journey

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Not journey or adventure.

Not crusade or expedition.

I'm not trying to insinuate purposeful / heroic.

I'm looking for a word relative to trial or crucible or calamity, but specific to a long and arduous journey.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mission. Quest. Thing.

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not provide clear criteria for useful answers – criteria that guide both answering and voting. This applies to word requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why.

Comment: See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Answer (score 12):

You could go straight to the classics and call it an **odyssey** - pretty much the defining work on long, arduous journeys.

**Trek** is also another good word to describe a long, and usually demanding, journey.

Comment: +1 for trek: "a long arduous journey, especially one made on foot."

Answer (score 3):

A  a long and arduous journey reminds me of **an ordeal**.

> - ordeal - (noun) a severe trial or experience,  an experience that is very unpleasant or difficult. [**MW**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ordeal)
>
> Being trapped in an elevator was a harrowing ordeal...
>
> - an extremely unpleasant experience, especially one that lasts for a long time.  [**MD**](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/ordeal)
>
> They have suffered a terrible ordeal.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case, the word "Quest" fits pretty well. A quest often involves a difficult journey and trials to test one's strength and person.

Comment: Op said NOT implying purpose

Comment: Edited to fit the question

Answer (score 1):

You've already been offered **trek**, which is good - particularly in British English where it's frequently used with a bit of humorous understatement as *a bit of a trek*. If that isn't quite what you want, *long hard **slog*** is idiomatic.